# How can I display parent and child terms from a CCK Taxonomy field in Pathauto?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, tokens, path-aliases

How can I have two (or more) different taxonomy vocabularies appear in my Pathauto settings at the same time? For example, if I want to use the 'location' vocabulary and the 'accommodation type' vocabulary to create a URL that would look like this:

```
/Holiday-Cottages/Anyregion/Anytown/Some-Holiday-Cottage
```

The example is made up of i) the accommodation type, ii) the locations (regional name down to the town name) and the node title.

How would I do this? Taxonomy only seems to allow me to use one vocabulary in my Pathauto settings.

I've spent the past few hours experimenting with Content Taxonomy Fields to do this, but that doesn't appear to allow me to display the entire termpath of parent and child terms in the location vocabulary (where you can see the region name and town name) in the same way that Taxonomy provides a [termpath-raw] token to use in the Pathauto alias.

This question is an off-shoot of my question here: [How can I create this sort of path structure?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14673/how-can-i-create-this-sort-of-path-structure)